# Why HourGlass not working with synchronous AJAX request in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am executing a function where first I am making cursor to wait state(hourglass) and then I am sending a synchrounous AJAX request .After getting the response I am making cursor to default state.

The Actual Code is this..

// tests the smtp settings
function TestSettings()
{
    var buttonparams= new Object();

```
buttonparams.IsCommandButton = true;
buttonparams.ButtonId = "testsettings";
buttonparams.ButtonText = "Sending Test Mail...";
buttonparams.ButtonOrigText = "Test Settings";

if(buttonparams.IsCommandButton == true)
    HandleButtonStatus(true, buttonparams);

var request = function()
{
    var ret = SendForm(buttonparams);

    alert(ret);

}
window.setTimeout(request, 0);
```

}

function SendForm(pButtonParams) 
{
    var http;
    var formdata;

```
http = yXMLHttpRequest();

http.open("POST", "./", false);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
http.setRequestHeader("Req-Type", "ajax");
formdata = xEncodePair("_object", "PrefMgr")+ "&";
formdata += xEncodePair("_action", "SmtpTest")+ "&";
formdata += GetEncodedFormData();   

http.send(formdata);

if(http.status == 200)
{   
    if(pButtonParams.IsCommandButton == true)
        HandleButtonStatus(false, pButtonParams);

    return (http.responseText);
}   
else
{

    return ("Error " + http.status + ": " + http.statusText);   
}
```

}

function HandleButtonStatus(pIsButtonStatusChange, pButtonParams)
{
    var button = yById(pButtonParams.ButtonId);

```
if(pIsButtonStatusChange)
{
        document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
    button.value = pButtonParams.ButtonText;
    button.disabled = true;

}
else
{
    document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    button.disabled = false;
    button.value = pButtonParams.ButtonOrigText;
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't use synchronous AJAX requests. They will lock the browser until the request is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign:

```
var st = document.body.style;
```

and then refer to `st` in both functions. This could be a scope issue in AJAX callback function.

EDIT: Use callback function to restore cursor shape. Don't forget to do the same in case AJAX call fails.

Comment: ya..now it is working fine..but one more issue..
I am creating an object before making cursor wait for my application purpose. If I am creating it, then again HourGlass is not working in google chrome. It I am commenting the create object statement then hour glass is working. why?

I will update the given code.

Comment: I think you should provide the full code or this function. There is something related to other things.

Comment: Now I got it. The request function is a classic closure. When you create var obj, you create a global context which keeps `request` function pointer from freeing.

Here is how it works: When `request' function is called first - it works as expected, sending AJAX request. On AJAX completion the context of `request` function is no more existing, unless you keep it by defining `obj` in outer scope, thus creating a closure.

Even synchronous AJAX calls works asynchronously via callback functions. You should better set cursor in callback function (using onstatechange) and not in `request`.

Comment: sorry..I might be confusing you..I am posting the actual code I have written

Comment: I think that Google Chrome does all XHR asynchronously (i.e. in separate thread), even it set to synchronous. Try to move all your actions to `onreadystatechange` callback function.