# Force UI repaint in Webkit (Safari & Chrome) right before Synchronous "Ajax" request

Tags: ajax, jquery, webkit

In a simple Ajax based website we are making some HttpRequests requests synchronously (I realize "synchronous Ajax" is somewhat of an oxymoron).  The primary reason this is being done synchronously vs. asynchronously is in order to simplify the programming model for some of those involved (long story).

Anyway, we want to be able to make a styling change (specifically, overlay the screen with semi transparent white as Google search does) right before the request is made, and then take it away when results come back.  Essentially this looks like:

```
load:function(url) {
    ....
    busyMask.className="Shown"; //display=block; absolute positioned full screen semi-transparent
    var dta=$.ajax({type:"GET",dataType:"json",url:url,async: false}).responseText;
    busyMask.className="Hidden"; //sets display=none;
    ...
    return JSON.parse(dta);
    }
```

It is well known a synchronous requests will lock the UI.  So not surprisingly, the white overlay never shows up in Safari and Chrome (it does in Firefox interestingly).  I've tried slowing the response way down and using a pink overlay so that it will be painfully obvious, but it just won't update the UI until after the request is complete.  Leaving the 'busyMask.className="Hidden"' part out will show the mask-- but only after the ajax request is complete.

I've seen many many tricks for forcing the UI to repaint (e.g. [Why HourGlass not working with synchronous AJAX request in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924681/why-hourglass-not-working-with-synchronous-ajax-request-in-google-chrome), http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript), but they all seem to be in conjunction with trying to show actual "permanent" DOM or styling updates, not with temporarily showing a style change while a synchronous request is made.

So is there a way to do this or am I fighting a losing battle?  It may be that we'll just need to switch to asynchronous requests on a case by case basis for the worst performing requests, which might be a decent way to tackle the learning curve issue...  But I'm hoping there is an outside the box answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Ok for the purpose of this question I will ignore the justification for why you require synchronous XHR requests. I understand that sometimes work constraints don't allow the use of the best practice solution and so we "make do" in order to get the job done. So lets focus on how to get synchronous ajax with visual updated working for you!

Well considering you are using jQuery for your XHR request, I'm going to assume its ok to use jQuery to show/hide the loading indicator and to handle any timing issues.

First let's set up a loading indicator in our markup:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
```

Now lets create some javascript:

```
// Show the loading indicator, then start a SYNCRONOUS ajax request
$('#loading').show().delay(100).queue(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({type:"GET",dataType:"json",url:"www.yoururl.com/ajaxHandler",async: false}).done(function(){
        //Do your success handling here
    }).fail(function() {
        //Do your error handling here
    }).always(function() {
        //This happens regardless of success/failure
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

First, we want to show our loading indicator and then give the browser a moment delay to repaint before our syncronous XHR request gets started. By using jQuery's `.queue()` method we are putting our `.ajax()` call in the default fx queue so that it won't execute until after the `.delay()` completes, which of course doesn't happen until after the `.show()` completes.

The jQuery `.show()` method changes the target element's CSS display style to block (or restores its initial value if assigned). This change in CSS will cause the browser to reflow (aka "redraw") as soon as it is able. The delay ensures that it will be able to reflow before the ajax call. The delay is not necessary in all browsers, but won't hurt any more than the number of milliseconds you specify (as usual, IE will be the limiting factor here, the other browsers are happy with a 1ms delay, IE wanted something a little more significant to repaint).

Here's a jsfiddle for you to test in a few browsers: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BenSwayne/ayhLg/3/)

Comment: "I will ignore the justification" - thank you, I appreciate it.  I shall digest your response in detail soon and see if I can apply it to what we are doing...

Comment: Unfortunately this approach will not help me because it is still essentially asynchronous -- the code to handle the success is disjointed from the code that makes the request.  I've added some clarifications in the code block in my post to help clear that up.  Again, realize this is not at all best practice... but handling the response in a separate function from where the request was made may be too cumbersome for some folks

Comment: I would also note this isn't the first time sync has been used as a way to simplify the development model, see Meteor for example: http://devopsangle.com/2012/04/25/pushing-data-not-pages-is-the-new-model-for-application-development/ (though of course very controversial)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think:

```
doSomethingBeforeRequest();
response = synchronousAjax();
doSomethingToTheDataAfterRequest(response);
```

that much "simpler" than:

```
doSomethingBeforeRequest();
properAjax(onSuccess(response){
   doSomethingToTheDataAfterRequest(response);
};
```

for your team? I'm not trying to argue, but I'm seriously curious of the justification...

The only benefit of the synchronous code i can think of is that you save a few curly braces; at the cost of freezing the browser.

If the browser doesn't complete the repaint before the request*, the only option I can think of is using a delay (as BenSwayne suggests); which would make the code as complex as the async call, and still make the browser unresponsive during the request.

*EDIT (some kind of an answer):*

Since JavaScript lacks threads; timeouts and ajax calls (that allows the browser to do something else before it's run; somewhat like sleep() in a threaded language is used ), is fairly fundamental to how you program JavaScript. I know it can be a bit of a learning curve at first (I know I was confused), but there is not really any sensible way to avoid learning it.

One situation I know people may be tempted to make synchronous calls is when several requests have to be made to the server in sequence; but you can do that asynchronous too, by nesting several calls like this:

```
doSomethingBeforeRequest1();
ajax(onSuccess(response1){
   doSomethingToTheDataAfterRequest1(response1);
   ajax(onSuccess(response2){
       doSomethingToTheDataAfterRequest2(response2);
   };
};
```

But unless each call is fairly slow to finish and you want to indicate progress at each step or something; I would rather recommend that you create a new service to combine the two operations with one call. (This service could just use the two existing services in sequence, if you still need them separately in some other cases).

(* I'm more surprised that Firefox DOES update the dom...)

Comment: To answer your question, primarily there is no such thing as "doSomethingBeforeRequest" and "doSomethingToTheDataAfterRequest".  Instead, there is a bunch of code in a function including local variables, then we need to grab some data, and then do a bunch more stuff.  To do it separately we would need to put those vars somewhere we could grab later on, which is not rocket science but is a different programming model.  For _me_ it is not really more difficult, but I'm not the only dev... I wish we could go back and do things differently from the beginning, but of course that is not easy...

Comment: ...I guess you are preaching to the choir here, but the sunday school class needs a simpler version of the sermon.

Answer (score 0):

I've maded some tests and came with some points:
http://jsfiddle.net/xVHWs/1/

Change your code to use jQuery's `hide()`, `show()` or `animate({ opacity: 'show' }, 'fast')` and `animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, 'fast')`
If you leave de functions without a time param or specify a 0 ms time, Firefox will show the overlay and hides it, the other browsers execute it to fast for you to see. Put a 100 millisecond in `show`, `hide`, or `animate` calls and you will see it.

Comment: Good try, but the UI changes don't show until after the request is complete.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajaxSetup({async:false});

    busyMask.className="Shown"; //display=block; absolute positioned full screen semi-transparent
    var dta=$.ajax({type:"GET",dataType:"json",url:url}).responseText;
    busyMask.className="Hidden"; //sets display=none;

$.ajaxSetup({async:true});
```

Comment: how you can say that. any reference. I guess it works on all browsers. Which part do you think won't work

Comment: From experience and from research I am certain I'm correct. JavaScript in browsers is single threaded per Frame (unless you involve Workers).  The code you've given has EXACTLY the same effect as the code I wrote (with async inside the options passed to $.ajax), and will not work in EXACTLY the same way.  Have you tested it in all browsers?

Comment: The code I am suggesting is different from your piece of code. Passing asyn false to the ajax request made the ajax asynchronous not the execution of the statements asynchronous. what my code does it made the each statement asynchronous. If you want to do that like your own code then place `busyMask.className="Hidden"; //sets display=none;` inside the success callback of the function.

Comment: Sorry, but "$.ajaxSetup({async:false});" definitely does not make each statement asynchronous.  There is nothing in JavaScript that has such an effect.

Comment: Did you tried. or you just saying based on your assumption. I know it does not make each statement synchronous. But sure does make ajax request synchronous/blocking. statement after the ajax request never get executed untill you get ajax response. But the code you've written is different. It make the ajax request synchronous but the statement after ajax request get executed immediately. In your case you've to write your code in complete/success function. But for my case you don't need the complete/success function. Thats the difference between your code any my code. If you try you'll know.